# How to generate a random string out of "KGBV" in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a game like rock, paper, scissors except with four different moves instead of three. The moves are all represented by K, G, B, V. For the computer to make a move, I need to generate a random letter to play against the human. I also need it to be a string so that I can compare it with the string that the human answers. Here is what I have but it only works with chars:

```
 public static String computerMove() {
    String move = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    String abc = "KGBV";

char letter = abc.charAt(rand.nextInt(abc.length()));


    if (letter == 'K') {
        move = K;
    } else if (letter == 'B') {
        move = B;
    } else if (letter == 'G') {
        move = G;
    } else if (letter == 'V') {
        move = V;
    }
    return move;



}
```

Comment: what is `rand_int` ? All your `move=...` are not valid java syntax

Comment: Maybe have a look at RandomStringUtils ? It can generate random strings out of a given set of possible chars. (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize an array with strings and take a random index within that array.

Something like this:

```
String[] moves = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
int index = rand.nextInt(moves.length);
String move = moves[index];
```

Comment: Why? Nothing wrong with taking random `char` from a `String`, like done in question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
String[] moves = {"G","K","N","V"};
return moves[rand.nextInt(moves.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a random single-character string from a string:

```
int r = rand.nextInt(string.length());
return string.substring(r, r + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static string computerMove() {
    String move;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum = rand.nextInt();

    if (randNum == 0)
        move = "k";
    else if (randNum == 1)
        move = "B";
    else if (randNum == 2)
        move = "G";
    else
        move = "V";

    return move;
}
```